# Mapbox GL Popup .setDOMContent example

Tags: dom, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to create a customized button to appear on a pop up which generates a dynamic link (a URL). I don't seem to be able to do this via the .setHTML because of the timing, can't bind a button to a function at runtime. So I thought I'd try the newish .setDOMContent 
There's zero information online as to how this feature works. I'm wondering if anyone has an example of this where a button is added to the popup that can run a function and send data.

Here's my very poor attempt at setting this up.

This function creates the popup

```
function GameObjectPopup(myObject) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(myObject.point, {
        layers: ['seed']
    });

    if (!features.length) {
        return;
    }

    var feature = features[0];
    // Populate the popup and set its coordinates
    // based on the feature found.
    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
        .setHTML(ClickedGameObject(feature))
        .setDOMContent(ClickedGameObject2(feature))
        .addTo(map);
};
```

This function adds the html via the .setHTML

```
function ClickedGameObject(feature){
    console.log("clicked on button");
    var html = '';

    html += "<div id='mapboxgl-popup'>";
    html += "<h2>" + feature.properties.title + "</h2>";
    html += "<p>" + feature.properties.description + "</p>";
    html += "<button class='content' id='btn-collectobj' value='Collect'>";
    html += "</div>";
    return html;
}
```

This function wants to add the DOM content via the .setDOMContent

```
function ClickedGameObject2(feature){
    document.getElementById('btn-collectobj').addEventListener('click', function()
    {
        console.log("clicked a button");
        AddGameObjectToInventory(feature.geometry.coordinates);
    });
}
```

I'm trying to pipe the variable from features.geometry.coordinates into the function AddGameObjectToInventory()

the error I'm getting when clicking on an object (so as popup is being generated)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Popup#setHTML`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Popup#setHTML) takes a string that represents some HTML content:

```
var str = "<h1>Hello, World!</h1>"
popup.setHTML(str);
```

while [`Popup#setDOMContent`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Popup#setDOMContent) takes actual HTML nodes. i.e:

```
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
h1.innerHTML="Hello, World";
popup.setDOMContent(h1);
```

both of those code snippets would result in identical Popup HTML contents. You wouldn't want to use both methods on a single popup because they are two different ways to do the same thing.

The problem in the code you shared is that you're trying to use the `setDOMContent` to add an event listener to your button, but you don't need to access the `Popup` object to add the event listener once the popup DOM content has been added to the map. Here is a working version of what I think you're trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/h4j554sk/